# How to apply if statements based on list element name in lapply

Tags: r, list, lapply

I am certain this has been asked in many different ways, but I am still struggling to find my answer. I would like to apply a function to a list that is different depending on the name of the list item.

Reproducible example and what I tried:

```
library(stringr)

miniList <- list(apple = "I love apples",
             burger = "I like burgers",
             cherry = "I don't like cherries")

output <- lapply(miniList, FUN = function(miniList) {
  for(i in miniList) {
    if(str_detect(names(miniList[i]), "a")) {
      nameItem <- "a" }
    if(str_detect(names(miniList[i]), "b")) {
      nameItem <- "b" }
    if(str_detect(names(miniList[i]), "c")) {
      nameItem <- "c"
    }
    }
  
  if(str_detect(nameItem, "a")) {
    "alright"
  }
  if(str_detect(nameItem, "b")) {
    "better"
  }
  if(str_detect(nameItem, "c")) {
    "cool"
  }
}
)
```

The ideal output would be:

```
> output
[[1]]
[1] "alright"

[[2]]
[1] "better"

[[3]]
[1] "cool"
```

My error:

```
Error in if (str_detect(names(miniList[i]), "a")) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Comment: Couple of initial issues, `str_detect()` will detect the character in any position sorry if the name is "abacus" it would match the a, b and c.  How do you want to handle that? Second `lapply` is a loop so the "miniList" in the function call is just a single value and thus "miniList[I]" does not exist since miniList is not a vector within the `lapply()` loop.

Comment: @Dave2e I created this example with the simplest use of str_detect, in my actual application I am accounting for that issue. Thanks for the clarification on my issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already iterating your list with `lapply`, I don't see why you should double loop it with a `for loop`. Moreover, to get the `names` of the list elements, you either have to use `lapply(names(miniList), ...)` or `lapply(1:length(miniList), ...)` as in my answer, otherwise the names attribute are not brought into the function defined in `lapply`. I suggest using another argument name (like `x` as in my answer) rather than the name of the list object itself in the `lapply` function to avoid confusion.

Also, use `else if` to catch other conditions missed in the first `if`, otherwise, the results from the last `if` will overwrite the previous ones.

```r
library(stringr)

lapply(1:length(miniList), FUN = function(x) {
    if (str_detect(names(miniList[x]), "a")) {
      nameItem <- "a"
    }
    else if (str_detect(names(miniList[x]), "b")) {
      nameItem <- "b"
    }
    else if (str_detect(names(miniList[x]), "c")) {
      nameItem <- "c"
    }
    if (str_detect(nameItem, "a")) {
      "alright"
    }
    else if (str_detect(nameItem, "b")) {
      "better"
    }
    else if (str_detect(nameItem, "c")) {
      "cool"
    }
  }
)

#> [[1]]
#> [1] "alright"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "better"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "cool"
```

Comment: The big conceptual point in your answer is to `lapply` over the index (or you could use the names) rather than over the list itself. With `lapply(1:length(miniList), ...` or `lapply(names(miniList), ...` you can access the names and the items. With `lapply(miniList, ...` (as in the question) the names are **not** brought along, and are difficult to access.

Comment: A related function is `purrr::imap`, which gives you both the item and the name in a convenient way.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks for the comment! I forgot to include the first point you mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Thank you @benson23 and @GregorThomas! I knew I was missing something as I'm stilll new to using lapply. The "1:length() "trick works great.